# RejectChanges Self-relation in DataSet

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, rollback, self-referencing-table

I have a problem rejecting a DataSet with self-related tables.

First I insert a parent row and a child row in a table. Then I call RejectChanges method from the table object or the same method from the DataSet. The RejectChagnes method throws RowNotInTableException.

This is the code to demostrate this ([TestRejectChanges.zip](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AreHIjL2VcoccAeMGoriUD3vfmU)):

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

//Parent row
DataSet.TABLERow parentRowOverDataSet = dataSet.TABLE.AddTABLERow(1, "Parent", null);

//Child row
dataSet.TABLE.AddTABLERow(2, "Child", parentRowOverDataSet);

//This line crash because the child row is detached before Rolback (in RejectChanges method code)
dataSet.TABLE.RejectChanges();

//Also crash
//foreach (DataSet.TABLERow row in dataSet.TABLE.ToList())
//{
//    row.RejectChanges();
//}

//Also crash
//dataSet.RejectChanges();
```

I tryed to override RejectChanges of DataTable but this method is not virtual. Is there any way to do this using RejectChanges of DataSet?

Answer (score 0):

I opened a MS Solve Case (using MSDN Lisence) and, after a month of waiting for their response, they wrote me the next:

> I did some research and had discussed with one of our team member in
>   PG and this appears to be a by design issue as of now.
>
> I went through your troubleshooting and suggestion:
>
> Thanks a lot for you feedback on this issue. At this point of time, I
>   am going to file a DCR (Design Change Request) to see if they can
>   consider this functionality in up-coming release.

Then it has no solution by the moment.